# How to customized font size and font orientation of X-axis in Chart Toolkit

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

How to customized font size and font orientation of X-Axis of chart toolkit in code behind?

I want to change the orientation of Motor Technology to vertical so that it will fit to my view. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need use a `LayoutTransformer` (found in the toolkit) in a new template for the axis label.

See this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/03/06/turn-your-head-and-check-out-this-post-how-to-easily-rotate-the-axis-labels-of-a-silverlight-wpf-toolkit-chart.aspx) for the Xaml you need.